# In Python, how can I create an in-memory Kubernetes pod object by reading YAML?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes pod YAML file. I want to read this file and create a Kubernetes pod object in memory, run some additional checks on this object and then submit this object to the K8s cluster.

I see some options such as [create_from_yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/utils/create_from_yaml.py). But, this directly creates the object in K8s. It doesn't give me a pod object to work with BEFORE actually running it.

Comment: Reading through the code you link to, it looks like it eventually calls `k8s_api.create_namespaced_KIND(body=yml_object)`, where `yml_object` is the parsed YAML file as a nested Python dictionary and `KIND` is `yml_object['kind']` with some case conversion.  Can you just read the YAML file and work with it in dictionary form?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you're trying to do? You can just read the YAML into a Python object by using the [`yaml` module](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) (`yaml.load`/`yaml.loads`).

Comment: I want to read a yaml file and create this [V1PodSpec object](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PodSpec.md). Preferably not have to do this by hand by populating one field at a time. Would be good if there are convenience methods for it. 

I will check if the `yaml module` can work for this.